# Rename and use multiple "Animation Nodes Object Containers"?

Tags: animation-nodes

When you use a "Separate Text Object" node, the resulting characters/objects are grouped together using a parent empty object, always named "Animation Nodes Object Container".

**Is there a way to change that object's name** without "breaking" the animation node?

That would be very useful for organizing the objects in a scene.

Which leads to another linked question: **is it possible to use more than one** "Container" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sorry, this is currently not supported. Maybe it will be in the future but I'm not sure.

You can however disable the parenting at all in the advanced settings in the node and parent them manually to an object. (Note: you'll have to do this again when you click the update button)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the development history of animation nodes, but i know nowaday it works like this:

[image]

and then you get the result in different collections which is pretty helpful.

I LOVE animation nodes ;)